# SharePoint online - Delete orphaned user C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, user-information-list

I want to delete Orphaned user from a site collection in C#. I can remove the user from group or remove the permission but I am not able to delete completely from the site collection ( user information list ).
Can someone please guide.

Comment: Are you open to use "PowerShell" for deleting orphaned users in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Leave the user there and remove their permissions. It doesn't help anything to remove them and if that user is referenced in any content on the site, that content risks getting broken.

Comment: Users who left the organization are given permissions to lists and one site has many lists and sub sites so removing those users completely can solve my issue. Those users have already left so there isn't any risk of things getting broken. We want to get rid of those users completely for audit purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing it just incase someone is looking for the solution that I just found.

```
web.SiteUsers.RemoveByLoginName("loginNameHere");
```

This will delete/remove the user from the site collection completely.